# Nginx ingress controller modsecurity

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, mod-security2, nginx-ingress

I enabled modsecurity: "true" and enable-owasp-modsecurity-crs: "true" via the configmap of the nginx ingresss controller according to [this link](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/third-party-addons/modsecurity/) . In the annotation of the ingress I set SecRuleEngine On.
When I use [nikto](https://github.com/sullo/nikto) to do some scans and try to trigger the owasp rules I only see 400 responses in the ingress logging. I would expect 403 responses. Anyone any idea on what I am doing wrong or what to check?

Comment: What do you get if you disable modsecurity?

Comment: Hi Rico, will try that today. To see what that does.

Comment: whats the result with disabled modsecurity?

Comment: I got it to work with modsecurity and owasp enabled via the configmap. The only thing I changed was the annotation in the ingress:
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      modsecurity_rules '
        SecRuleEngine On
        SecAuditLog /var/log/modsec/audit.log
        SecAuditLogParts ABCIJDEFHZ
        SecAuditEngine RelevantOnly
        SecRuleRemoveById 932140
      ';

I had to change "SecAuditLog /var/log/modsec/audit.log". Changed it to SecAuditLog /var/log/modsec_audit.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Followed the instructions on:
https://karlstoney.com/2018/02/23/nginx-ingress-modsecurity-and-secchatops/

The only thing I had to change was "SecAuditLog /var/log/modsec/audit.log". Changed it to SecAuditLog /var/log/modsec_audit.log